# I need to install flash builder in Ubuntu-14.04 what repository should i add?

Tags: flex4, adobe, ubuntu-14.04

I want to install flash builder-4 in Ubuntu-14.04-what repository should i add?
I tried in some sites like http://blog.int3ractive.com/2010/10/using-flash-builder-4-on-ubuntu.html , but i failed to get.

Answer (score 0):

You can install flashbuilder in linux using wine. Here is a link with detailed instruction: https://gist.github.com/j-mcnally/708584c913e41dd208c1